# How to add Poco library in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, poco-libraries

It's been a while since I've programmed in C++ and right now I'm struggling with this Poco library I'm trying to add to do some HTTP requests.

First of all, where do I add poco files, somewhere in my project perhaps?

Secondly, I've read something about command prompt and running a script that will compile files but I have to give it an argument which is my visual studio version and the choices are from 70 to 110. How do I find out which one I should use?

If someone could provide me a step-by-step guide, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Are you referring to [POCO C++ Libraries and Tools](http://pocoproject.org)? If so,

1. Download POCO C++ libraries [here](http://pocoproject.org/download/index.html)
2. Extract(eg: extract to C:\poco-1.4.6)
3. Find appropriate solution file and build.

   - build_vs71.cmd ==> Visual Studio .NET 2003
   - build_vs80.cmd ==> Visual Studio 2005
   - build_vs90.cmd ==> Visual Studio 2008
   - build_vs100.cmd ==> Visual Studio 2010
   - build_vs110.cmd ==> Visual Studio 2012 
     [For more info about visual studio versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Version_history)
     For example, if you want to use poco lib in Visual Studio 2005 Project, you need to build with build_vs80.cmd.Once you have built successfully, you can see all poco static lib in {POCO Folder}\lib. (eg: C:\poco-1.4.6\lib)
4. Create new project in visual studio and add header path to **Project->Properties->C/C++-> Additional Include Directories**(eg: If you want to use POCO Foundation, add "C:\poco-1.4.6\Foundation\include")
5. Add POCO lib path to **Project->Properties-> Linker-> General-> Additional Library Directories.** (eg: C:\poco-1.4.6\lib)
6. Add POCO lib files names to **Project->Properties->Linker->Input-> Additional Dependencies** (eg: PocoNetd.lib )
7. Now you can start using POCO libraries in your project.

You may also want to check POCO HTTP sample projects which are located at **{POCO Folder}\Net\samples.** (eg: C:\poco-1.4.6\Net\samples)

Comment: Thank you for writing a quick concise guide on how to do that, much appreciated.

Comment: Do I need to add to "Additional Include Directories" all "include" dirs? Thanks in advance

Comment: rodi, I think you need to add only the inclue from the lib you will use, like, Foundation/Net/etc... if you use only one, just add that