# I can't link my Visual Studio 2010 project with Poco C++ libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, poco

I'm trying to use Poco C++ library in a Visual Studio 2010 project. I've done everything that is specified in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269755/how-to-add-poco-library-in-visual-studio-2010) instructions, but still getting an error when I try to execute my code, because PocoFoundation.dll can't be found. I've checked that the DLL is where I tell Visual Studio to find it, but still getting same error

Comment: You may have to modify the environment variable `PATH` to indicate the location of DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the error is "dll-name.dll is not found"

The instructions posted, in the link you've provided, are for static linking of the poco libraries.

DLL's are linked at the runtime of the executable, where as the instructions tell you how to compile the program successfully

You have to tell OS and **not** Visual studio where to look for the DLL.

[Search path for DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) -specifies where the OS looks for DLL and in what order

The link tells you the order which is roughly the following :

1) **Directory in which the executable resides.**

2) **The current directory** ( i.e working directory if you are running the executable from visual studio)

3)Windows system directory ( you don't want to add anything manually here)

4)Windows directory ( same as above , don't tinker with this one as well)

5)**All the locations specified using PATH variable** ( NOTE: PATH can be set using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119539/visual-studio-how-to-set-path-to-dll) from visual studio or can be set through control panel as well)

---

So two ways to solve the problem :

1)your **dll-name.dll** should reside in any of the **specified folders** above.

Or

2) if your dll is in folder C:\path\where\dll\is\

**set PATH = PATH;C:\patj\where\dll\is**

Comment: Do you know the feeling when you realize something that immediately sounds obvious? That's my feeling now. I'm silly :-). Many thanks! It's working.

Comment: Great!Well, it happens all the time, the solution is staring right at your face and for some reason your brain ignores it! good luck with your work.