# Linking Problems with Poco library

Tags: c++, dll, linker, poco

I work with Visual Studio 2012 and have problems getting started with the poco library. 
The following Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Poco/StreamCopier.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h"
#include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketStream.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
Poco::Net::SocketAddress sa("www.appinf.com", 80);
Poco::Net::StreamSocket socket(sa);
Poco::Net::SocketStream str(socket);
str << "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
"Host: www.appinf.com\r\n"
"\r\n";

str.flush();
Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(str, std::cout);
return 0;
}
```

Throws the following error:

```
C:\Users\christof\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\FTP\poco-1.4.6p3\poco-1.4.6p3\bin\PocoNet.dll : fatal error LNK1107: Invalid or broken file: Reading 0x2C0 not possible.
```

The PocoNet.dll is exactly at the right place. I added the dll in the additional dependencies und the lib location too. But still I get the same error.
I assume that is an absolute beginner failure, because I'm an absolute beginner in working with c++ and Visual Studio. I assume I haven't linked correctly, but I don't know better.
I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14767964/2050745

Comment: Thanks for the link; I ve done everything exactly like in the link. But the error still occurs. Have someone an antother idea. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all your calling application must load `PocoFoundation.dll`, after which you can use the class `Poco::SharedLibrary` to load `PocoNet.dll` and `Poco::ClassLoader`
to instantiate objects that you need.
Every `PocoXxxx.dll` can be loaded statically if you define `POCO_STATIC` or dynamically if you define `POCO_DLL`.
For more informations see [PocoSharedLibraries.pdf](http://pocoproject.org/slides/120-SharedLibraries.pdf)